# num_rows doesn't work with prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a test code where I try to reach my database information. But one script that uses prepared statements does not work, and second without prepared statements works just fine.

```
$userzzz = "test";
```

With this script, I get "BAD" as the result

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userzzz);
$stmt->execute();
echo $stmt->num_rows();
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0){
echo "good";    
} else {
echo "bad";
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your web server's error logs. You're not doing any real error checking here.

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);` -- still using $username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in object oriented mysqli, num_rows is not a function, it's an attribute of the result (stmt). You need `$stmt->num_rows;` not `$stmt->num_rows();`

In your second example, you're not using (), you are doing it correctly, hence why it functions in the second but not the first.

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT unique_col FROM user WHERE username=?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userzzz);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$rows = $stmt->num_rows;
if ($rows > 0){
echo "good";    
} else {
echo "bad";
}
```

I also added `$stmt->store_result()`. It is finicky and num_rows will be 0 unless you store the result before you run `$stmt->num_rows;`

I'd also use a unique column instead of *, such as `id` for example.

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: The above is syntactically correct. Echo $rows and see what it has

Comment: Seems that store_result() solved the problem. It's strange cause I had previous projects where I didn't use function to store results but it worked just fine.

Answer (score 4):

From the manual,

> The use of `mysqli_stmt_num_rows()` depends on whether or not you used `mysqli_stmt_store_result()` to buffer the entire result set in the statement handle.
>
> If you use `mysqli_stmt_store_result()`, `mysqli_stmt_num_rows()` may be called immediately.

Which means that you'll have to use `$stmt->store_result();` after executing, but before accessing the `num_rows` property.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userzzz);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
echo $stmt->num_rows;
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0){
    echo "good";    
} else {
    echo "bad";
}
```

If you don't do this, the rows won't be buffered into the memory, and there's no way of knowing how many rows actually was returned, until you loop through the entire set of data (by `while ($stmt->fetch())`).

- [PHP.net on `mysqli_stmt_store_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to bind the results after you execute, this will work in your case (works for me):

```
<?php
$userzzz = 'test';
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userzzz);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
echo $stmt->num_rows();
if ($stmt->num_rows() > 0){
echo "good";    
} else {
echo "bad";
}
?>
```